# SwiftMailer: Timeout or File size issue

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I use SwiftMailer version Swift-5.0.3 (most recent release).

I have a form and a PHP file process very simple:

```
<?php

require_once '../lib/swift_required.php';

// Transport Protocol
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

//Variables Initialization
$nom = $_POST ['nom'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$textform = $_POST ['textform'];

//Message creation
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setFrom($email, $nom);
$message->setSubject('Any text for the Subject');
$message->setTo('test@test.com');
$message->setBody($textform, 'text/html');

//Attachment  
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['photo']['name']);


//Message Attachement
$message->attach($attachment);

//Sending the e-mail
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);

if ($mailer->send($message)) {
    header("Location: ../forms/thanks.html");
} else {
    echo "Failure sending message";
}
?>
```

THE ISSUE:

When I use the form trying to upload a file of more than **800kb** or if Upload time seems higher than **8 seconds** my PHP process is suddenly stopped with the Navigator (I.E.) message "Page cannot be displayed".

Is there any mean to fix that ?

--

Oscar

From Paris, France

Comment: Try enabling error messages in your script (or in your `php.ini`) with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.  Then update your question with the actual error you receive.  It is most likely a PHP max execution time configuration you'll have to fix, but its hard to say without an error.

Comment: Thank you very much Sam for your quick answer. I have no access to my my PHP.ini due to restrictions by my Internet Provider. I added your two instructions error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); like that in my PHP process file (I'm not a PHP specialist). But if file uploaded >800kb always the same reaction of my Navigator "Page cannot be displayed". Is it possible to fix the mas execution time elsewhere than in the PHP.ini ? Regards. /Oscar (Paris, France)

Comment: You would (most likely) be able to modify the PHP configuration directly from the .php file with `ini_set()` (this is what I had you doing in my first comment for debugging).  Did you receive any additional errors (not just `Page cannot be displayed`) when adding those two functions in?  I am trying to debug whether it is a max execution time or max upload size error.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks very very much for your kind support. I have good news to fix hopefully the issue. Firstly I wrote another basic code without using SwiftMailer, unfortunately, Timeout or Filesize problem remain the same. BUT... what is terrific, re-using the initial Swiftmailer code with another Navigator (Opera or Mozilla Firefox), I have absolutely NOT ANY PROBLEM to send my form including huge file size. So now I'm 100% sure the dysfunction comes from Internet Explorer (v11).  I probably need to implement a PHP waiting page while file uploading. But how? Regards. /Oscar (Paris - France)

Comment: Breaking news: after testing on another computer with Internet Explorer v11, everything works perfectly. It appears now that the Timeout issue is specifically localized on MY computer: Windows 8.1 / Internet Explorer. I would appreciate any help, if somebody could tell me how to manage that. Thanks to all. Oscar (Paris, France).

Comment: Honestly not sure if there is much you can do, Oscar.  It seems like this is a Windows 8.1 + IE 11 issue.  If you make the script public I can try uploading something since I have a similar build laying around.  Make sure you have all Windows and IE updates installed, they may have patched the issue.

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks very much. It was indeed an I.E issue. Problem solved. Here is the solution: To change the default time-out setting for Internet Explorer, follow these steps:
 
1.    Start Registry Editor.
2.    Locate the following subkey:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
3.    In this subkey, add a ReceiveTimeout DWORD entry that has a value of (<number of seconds>)*1000. For example, if you want the time-out duration to be 8 minutes, set the value of the ReceiveTimeout entry to 480000 (<480>*1000).
4.    Restart the computer. Best regards /Oscar

Comment: Good find Oscar.  You should write that comment into an answer and select it so that others can benefit.